# Is there any way to change notification image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i want to show or change present image in notification with latest image icon, the image icon will be provided either in the notification data or saved previously in the app [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg6Gr.png) and this one image [image: and this one]

i want that if notification came on the IOS device then the image in the notification will show accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this text from iOS Human Interface Guidelines

---

A banner is a small translucent view that appears onscreen and then disappears after a few seconds. Users can also see a version of the banner on the lock screen and in the Notifications view of Notification Center. In the banner, iOS displays your notification message and the small version of your app icon (to learn more about the small app icon, see App Icon). Users tap the banner to dismiss it and switch to the app that sent the notification.

---

I believe that  you can't change it, but may be if you change some pictures in App icon source, you will achieve the necessary result, but I repeat, hardly everything will correctly work

for example [image]

U can try to change Spotlight images or any else....